# Custom hosting and "Silverlight-enabled WCF service"

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-hosting

I'd like my WP7 to be able to talk to a service on my local computer. For various reasons it would be more convenient if this service was hosted in a custom host, i.e. an app running locally. However, if I understand correctly "Silverlight-enabled WCF service" need asp.net compatibility, therefore must be hosted in IIS, is this correct?

If so, is there anyway to work round this and get a "Silverlight-enabled WCF service" running in a custom host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Silverlight-enabled WCF Service is just a simplified item template from a regular WCF service.  It was originally added because the default binding for WCF services wasn't supported in Silverlight, and caused a lot of angst for new Silverlight developers.  You should be able to use the regular WCF item in a regular project (e.g. console app) and you'll just have to adjust the bindings.

(Also of note is that the Silverlight-enabled WCF template uses a single code file instead of separating out the service interface from the class implementation.)

Comment: Your right, WP7's silverlight seems pretty fussy about the type of service it accepts. I ended up creating a new  wcf web project adding a "Silverlight-enabled WCF service" and then porting this, with all its settings, to the custom host. Seems you also need to fiddle about with the "Configure Service Reference ..." options to get collections as parameters working.